# Find last value in column A, if condition in column B is true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got hiking distance data from a start point in column A and a column with a yes/no condition (let's say a "Y" denotes a campsite, for example).

What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the distance between each distance marker in column A that has the condition "Y" in column B. (Desired output is column C.)

```
A     B     C
--------------
0     Y
12
26    Y    26       (26 - 0 = 26)
57
124   Y    98       (124 - 26 = 98)
137
152   Y    28       (152 - 124 = 28)
169
.     .    .
.     .    .
.     .    .
```

I can pull out the distance from column A with a simple IF statement, but that doesn't get me anywhere, of course.

I've searched the Internet extensively and there are a ton of threads out there about finding the last value or last non-empty value in a column.

So I've tried to use INDEX, FILTER, and LOOKUP in all sorts of combinations, but sadly nothing produces the result I'm looking for.

The tricky part, I guess, is to find the last value with a Y **above** the "current" Y (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Is it possible to swap Column A and Column B position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B="y", A2:A-iferror(vlookup(row(A2:A)-1, filter({row(A2:A), A2:A}, len(B2:B)),2)),))
```

and see if that works?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're a wizard, Harry ... er JPV. That does exactly what I wanted. Thank you so very much!